# Image are reloaded automatically when I go back to previous screen

Tags: flutter, dart

`When i go back from screen 2 to screen 1. Then images are reloaded automatically. Can anyone help me to stop reloaded.`

I have `already tried the cacheExtent` in ListView and also the `cache_network_image` plugin but does not work.

Comment: what are you using `push` or `replace`  on `routing`?

Comment: I am using .pushscreen not pushreplacement

Comment: can you add  those 2 widgets

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because you might be loading multiple images on screen 2 and to manage memory images are cleared from cache memory.

So the solution is to increase default image cache size, create custom class as below which will override default size of the image cache

```
class NetworkImageCache extends WidgetsFlutterBinding {
  @override
  ImageCache createImageCache() {
    ImageCache imageCache = super.createImageCache();
    /// Set your image cache size to 500 Mb
    imageCache.maximumSizeBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 500;
    return imageCache;
  }
}
```

and call this class as below in main

```
void main() async {
  NetworkImageCache();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Recommended is that you should enable it in release mode only